# Cant get firebase Auth dotnet to work in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, firebase

I'm currently using this library's with vb.net:
firebase-authentication-dotnet
firebase-database-dotnet

They include examples for C#, but not vb.net
So far I got pulling data out, But I can't get authentication to work, here is my code:

```
Dim authProvider = New FirebaseAuthProvider(New FirebaseConfig("api"))
Dim auth = authProvider.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync("1@1.com","test123").Result
Dim firebase = New FirebaseClient("myurl")
 Dim dinos = Await firebase _
           .Child("dinosaurs") _
           .OrderByKey() _
           .StartAt("pterodactyl") _
           .LimitToFirst(2) _
           .OnceAsync(Of Dinosaur)

        For Each dino In dinos
            RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text & vbNewLine & $"{dino.Key} is {dino.Object.Height}m high."
            ' Console.WriteLine($"{dino.Key} is {dino.Object.Height}m high.")
        Next
```

Problem is it just hangs, no response no error and no results.

Also tried creating a user with this code:

```
Dim auth = Await authProvider.CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync("idk@idk.com", "test")
```

No luck.
What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: It's quite possible that the way the C# SDK persists the authentication state is incompatible when running the code under a VB.net environment. Could you make use of the [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth) instead?

Comment: not 100% sure hot to use it, kind of do, but not fully. When making a request, i'm using this code:

        Try
           
            request = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=[apiihere]"), HttpWebRequest)
            response = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
reader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())

         Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd())
        Finally
            If Not response Is Nothing Then response.Close()
        End Try
but where do i shove email and password strings?